# How can I fix the warping issue in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What my blue fish should do: Move around to random positions on the screen and when you touch it with the mouse, it should flee to a random location fast, then continue swimming.

What my blue fish does: After fleeing, it warps to a random location.

How can I fix the warping, so that the fish continues swimming from its current position after fleeing?

```js
/*globals $:false, window:false*/
$("#blueFishId").animate({}, function() {
  blueFish(this)
});

function blueFish(IdRef) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).width() - $(IdRef).width()))
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).height() - $(IdRef).height()))
  $(IdRef).delay(500).animate({
    top: y,
    left: x
  }, 5000, function() {
    blueFish(IdRef);
  });
}
$("#blueFishId").on("mouseenter", function() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).width() - $("#blueFishId").width()))
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).height() - $("#blueFishId").height()))
  $("#blueFishId").animate({
    top: y,
    left: x
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
img {
  position: relative;
}

#blueFishId {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="blueFish" id="blueFishId" src="images/fish2.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you need to clear the queued animation on mouseover and you also need to stop the current animation that's executing. You can achieve this by calling `stop()` and also putting the `delay()` call *after* the `animate()`. Also note that you can DRY up the logic by just calling your function from within `mouseenter` after you `stop()` the current animation. Try this:

```js
var $fish = $('#blueFishId');

function moveFish($fish) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).width() - $fish.width()))
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(window).height() - $fish.height()))
  $fish.animate({
    top: y,
    left: x
  }, 5000, function() {
    moveFish($fish);
  }).delay(500);
}

$fish.on("mouseenter", function() {
  $fish.stop(true);
  moveFish($fish);
});

moveFish($fish);
```

```css
img {
  position: relative;
}

#blueFishId {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="blueFish" id="blueFishId" src="images/fish2.png">
```

You may also want to consider making the fish move a greater distance on `mouseenter` to make it look more like it's 'fleeing' the mouse.